# Struggling setting up saving with CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

So I've really been struggling with CoreData. I started over my app with very basic info to get the CoreData info setup first. I have a model of data called 'SleepModel' which has a string (DatePicked) [yes I know this will need to be a Date eventually], string (hoursSlept), and UUID (id). My CoreData file Entity is called 'Item.' I think I've coded the ListViewModel correctly to save the data, but when trying to display it, its giving me errors. Some things are commented out as I was experimenting with different code. The error is showing on the ListRowView() section stating that it can't covert data FetchedResults to SleepModel.

**ListViewModel:**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "SleepModel")
    @Published var sleep: [SleepModel] = [
        SleepModel(datePicked: "09/22/22", hoursSlept: "8.5", feelingGood: true),
        SleepModel(datePicked: "09/21/22", hoursSlept: "7.5", feelingGood: false),
        SleepModel(datePicked: "09/20/22", hoursSlept: "9.5", feelingGood: true)
    ]
    
    init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to load Core Data \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Data Saved!!")
        }   catch {
            print("Save Failed :(")
        }
    }
 func addSleep(hoursSlept: String, datePicked: String, feelingGood: Bool, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let sleep = Item(context: context)
        sleep.id = UUID()
        sleep.hoursSlept = hoursSlept
        sleep.datePicked = datePicked
        sleep.feelingGood = feelingGood
        
        save(context: context)
    }
}
}
```

**ListView:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    
//    @EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.id, order: .reverse)]) var sleep: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sleep) { sleepItem in
                ListRowView(sleepItem: sleep)
            }
      //      .onDelete(perform: listViewModel().deleteSleep)
      //      .onMove(perform: listViewModel().moveSleep)
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .navigationTitle(" Sleep Log")
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading: EditButton(),
            trailing:
                NavigationLink("Add", destination: AddView())
        )
        
    }
}

struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ListView()
        }
    }
}
```

**ListRowView:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListRowView: View {
    
    let sleepItem: SleepModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("\(sleepItem.datePicked)").bold()
                Text("\(sleepItem.hoursSlept) ahi").font(.system(size:8))
            }
            VStack {
                Text("\(sleepItem.hoursSlept) hours slept")
                Text("\(sleepItem.hoursSlept) leaks/hr").font(.system(size:8))
            }
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: sleepItem.feelingGood ? "hand.thumbsup.circle.fill" : "hand.thumbsdown.circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(sleepItem.feelingGood ? .green : .red)
        }
        .font(.title3)
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: *its giving me errors*. What errors? And where do you put the managed object context into the `environment`? I – and Apple – recommend to use a singleton for the CoreData stack

Comment: the structure isnt right and we dont use view model objects in SwiftUI. Try the app template in xcode with core data checked first.

Comment: The error is showing on the ListRowView() section stating that it can't covert data FetchedResults to SleepModel.. If this isn’t correct, what is the right way to setup core data for the app? I actually was following a tutorial for this so I’m surprised to hear that it’s not correct

Comment: I would suggest first writing an app (by following a tutorial) that doesn't include Core Data and then add core data when you feel more comfortable with swift and swiftui because Core Data can be difficult to learn and if you also struggle with other parts it can be a bit overwhelming.